# Why doesn't Java recognize my ArrayList in an overloaded constructor situation

Tags: java, collections, constructor

I have two constructors setup like so:

```
public XMessage(Information info, List<Object> results) {
    this.information = info;
    this.results = results;
}

public XMessage(Information info, Object result) {
    this(info, Collections.singletonList(result));
}
```

I create the XMessage object by passing in an Information object and an ArrayList object. When I inspect the result, it is a singleton list wrapping the ArrayList item. Why doesn't Java use the more appropriate constructor and what are my options to force it?

Comment: What exactly are your parameters, whats the generic type of the arraylist?

Comment: What you describe and posted will work as you intended.  What is the code actually calling the constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Calls first constructor:

```
new XMessage(information, new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Calls second constructor:

```
new XMessage(information, new ArrayList<String>());
```

`ArrayList<String>()` is not treated as `List<Object>` while `ArrayList<Object>` is. Consider using the following constructor:

```
public XMessage(Information info, List<? extends Object> results)
```

as *@LuiggiMendoza* suggested below.

Comment: Also to pass a List of any object, it should use a wildcard: `public XMessage(Information info, List<? extends Object> results)`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `List<String>` is not a subclass (or otherwise substituable for) a `List<Object>` is that the callee might well want to add any objects to the list, and `List<String>` is supposed to be type safe.

You can read more about your options [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Java) if you cannot simply use identical typing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the answers above and thought they were working for me but it ended up being a false positive. I went with this constructor and its working for me:

```
public XMessage(Information info, Object result) {
    this(info, result instanceof List ? (List<Object>) result : Collections.singletonList(result));
}
```